# ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Anyone know how I can create this query using ActiveRecord rather than using SQL?

```
@leaderboard = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT name, street, town, county,        avg(volume_used)  FROM `DBName`.`events
join DBName.households on idhouseholds = events.household_id 
group by household_id
order by volume_used ASC;");
```

Comment: Your ActiveRecord connection will be to a specific database.  You'll need to connect to `DBName` (by specifying the correct params in database.yml) before running your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
@leaderboard = Event.select([:name,:street,:town,:county,'avg(volume_used) as avg_used']).joins(:households).group('events.household_id').order('volume_used asc')
```

assuming that by `idhouseholds` you actually meant `households.id` and that you want to order by the aggregate average field you are selecting.

Comment: thanks Ben, tried that and its giving me incorrect averages and its dropping records too. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your table definitions?

Comment: create_table :events do |t|
  t.integer :id
  t.datetime :start_time
  t.datetime :end_time
  t.float :volume_used
  t.integer :inferred_appliance_id
  t.integer :household_id
  t.timestamps
    end

Comment: create_table :households do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :number
  t.string :street
  t.string :town 
  t.string :county
 end

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated the code in the answer (the order and group clauses weren't quite right) - give that a try.